# Minimal API - 415 error when using multipart/form content type and custom body model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, http-status-code-415, minimal-apis

First of all, here is a POST mapping that DOES work :

```
app.MapPost("formulary/uploadSingle/{oldSys}/{newSys}",
            async (HttpRequest request, string oldSys, string newSys) =>
            {
                return await MapUploadSingleFileEndpoint(request, oldSys, newSys);

            }).Accepts<IFormFile>("form-data")
            .Produces(StatusCodes.Status200OK)
            .Produces(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);
```

The MapUploadSingleFileEndpoint method uses the entire body to get the file like so :

```
using var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8);
```

This works flawlessly from the Swagger UI, it shows the 2 parameters plus a file selection dialog and hitting execute returns a 200.  I can then copy the file locally on the server and manipulate it at will.  Do note that changing form-data to ANYTHING else results in Swagger not showing a file section dialog.

Here is the issue.  I need an endpoint that takes the same parameters except it needs 2 files to work.  Because I'm reading the whole body to get a single file in the previous method I can obviously not do the same here.  Even if that wasn't the case the IFormFile type produces a file selector dialog that only allows a single selection.  I tried changing the accept to `IFormFileCollection` or `List<IFormFile>` but that does not work, there is no file chooser on the Swagger UI.  I decided to try creating this custom request model :

```
public class MultipleFormularyFilesRequest
{
    public string OldExternalSystemName { get; set; }

    public string NewExternalSystemName { get; set; }

    public IFormFile FirstFile { get; set; }

    public IFormFile SecondFile { get; set; }
}
```

I also added the following endpoint mapping :

```
app.MapPost("formulary/uploadMultiple",
            async (MultipleFormularyFilesRequest request) =>
            {
                int i = 0;

            }).Accepts<MultipleFormularyFilesRequest>("multipart/form-data")
            .Produces(StatusCodes.Status200OK)
            .Produces(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);
```

This DOES result in Swagger UI having 4 parameters under request body and 2 file selectors.  Unfortunately when I hit execute I get this 415 error :

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.BadHttpRequestException: Expected a supported JSON media type but got "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryUzAAKF4zHMbAvtpr".
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.Log.UnexpectedContentType(HttpContext httpContext, String contentType, Boolean shouldThrow)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayClass46_3.<<HandleRequestBodyAndCompileRequestDelegate>b__2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because FromBody binding is not supported in .NET Core Minimal APIs. As an alternative, you can customize the parameter binding. Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040#custom-binding). Here is an example code.

```
public class MultipleFormularyFilesRequest
{
    public string? OldExternalSystemName { get; set; }

    public string? NewExternalSystemName { get; set; }

    public IFormFile? FirstFile { get; set; }

    public IFormFile? SecondFile { get; set; }

    public static async ValueTask<MultipleFormularyFilesRequest?> BindAsync(HttpContext context,
                                                   ParameterInfo parameter)
    {
        var form = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
        var firstFile = form.Files["FirstFile"];
        var secondFile = form.Files["SecondFile"];
        var oldExternalSystemName = form["OldExternalSystemName"];
        var newExternalSystemName = form["NewExternalSystemName"];
        return new MultipleFormularyFilesRequest
        {
            FirstFile = firstFile,
            SecondFile = secondFile,
            OldExternalSystemName = oldExternalSystemName,
            NewExternalSystemName = newExternalSystemName
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It is in .NET 7!

Comment: @davidfowl Reading the docs, still says not supported.  Link to show how to accomplish it?  Thanks.

Comment: @Terry Did you check this? https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040#file-uploads-using-iformfile-and-iformfilecollection

Comment: Thanks.  I misunderstood @davidfowl comment (or rather the question)...I read it and was thinking [FromBody] was requested and that was implemented in .NET 7.  But it is only files.  Will have to figure out how to deal with needing to bind a model [FromBody] in minimal APIs.